# Windows Unkillable Executable file (.exe)

Tags: c#, windows, service, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I would like to create an "Unkillable" Windows .exe file, similar to an antivirus process/service, with the condition that neither the user nor the administrator can stop or terminate the process.

I created a service using the C# language in Visual Studio. After successfully installing the service's executable and the service itself, I encountered an "Access Denied" error when using Microsoft Management Console. However, when attempting the same operation directly on the executable of that service, it did not yield the same result; the administrator was still able to stop and end the service.
[Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItLNS.png)

Comment: Ultimately, you cannot stop an administrator from doing anything. And: if it were possible, how would you ever get rid of the process again?